# JSTL c tags not processed in JSP code embedded in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

We use JSTL tags in our JSP pages. The project worked fine with our previous server configuration. Now, the servers have been migrated to newer versions. Now, all the `c` tags are processed correctly in JSP code. But the `c` tags inside JavaScript are not processed, and the tags are sent to our client as-is. What's wrong with the following code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// String Export for JS Files
var langSectionViewState = new Array();
 <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
    <c:set var="langId" value="${message['langId']}"/>
    langSectionViewState["${langId}"] = ${message['bShow']};
 </c:forEach>
</script>
```

The same `c` tags are processed and work well when they are in JSP code. The `c` tags which are inside `<script></script>` are not processed. What is a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: You remember to include core taglib?

Comment: Yes Neil. The C tags in the jsp are processed. But the c tags inside the javascript were not processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// String Export for JS Files
var langSectionViewState = new Array();
</script>

<c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">`enter code here`
    <c:set var="langId" value="${message['langId']}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    langSectionViewState["${langId}"] = ${message['bShow']};
</script>
 </c:forEach>
```